# How do I pass Bootstrap-tags input as an array to a form?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tags

I need to pass an array to a form based on what is returned from bootstrap-tags input. I have followed the documentation to try and retrieve the array using the following code:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name = "language" value="Javascript,Ruby" id = "languages" data-role="tagsinput" />
  <input type='hidden' name='languages_hidden[]' id = "languages_hidden" value='' />
  <input name="save" onclick="mySubmit()" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
<script> 
 function mySubmit() {
 document.getElementById('skills_hidden').value = $("#skills").tagsinput('items')
 }
</script>
```

I expect the resulting array that is passed on to be in the format when I click the submit button:

```
["Javascript", "Ruby"]
```

However, I see that that is actually how the array is passed on:

```
["Javascript, Ruby"]
```

How do i rectify this?

Comment: For stable version : v0.8.0, you may use `<select multiple name="sel[]"></select>`. Ref link:
https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to the following. Also added a fall back just in case.

```
function mySubmit() {
  document.getElementById('skills_hidden').value = ($("#skills").tagsinput('items') || [''])[0].split(', ');
}
```

*Edit: Updated function to reflect returning of an array.*